# Bootstrap broker disconnected while connecting with Kafka AWS

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

we are working on spring boot with kafka and facing `[Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 ( EC2 ip) could not be established. Broker may not be available`.

Our Kakfa is running on aws EC2 and our producer and consumer are spring boot application and we want to send message from producer to consumer using aws kafka

**yml file : producer configuration**

```
  kafka-bootstrap-servers: EC2'ip:9092

  kafka-topic-name: my_notification
```

**KafkaProducerConfig.java**

```
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return configProps;
```

**yml file : consumer configuration**

```
  kafka-bootstrap-servers: EC2'ip:9092

  kafka-topic-name: my_notification

  kafka-group-id: group-id

  kafka-topic-partitions: 1

  kafka-topic-replicas: 1
```

**KafkaConsumerConfig.java**

```
  Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, emailGroupId);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props,
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(MyModel.class));
```

while sending a message from producer to consumer we are getting error and we are not able to get message at consumer side.

we have changed advertised.listeners and listeners value's with ip in server.properties file.

after 60000 ms we got below error

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic  not present in metadata after 60000 ms.`

Comment: Why not use MSK instead of EC2? Does this help? https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: hello @OneCricketeer I have tried MSK instead of EC2 .

Now I am getting following error.
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers

Comment: Hard to say what the issue might be without seeing your code. I assume you copied the client properties directly from the MSK dashboard? And you're using public addresses to the cluster?

Comment: As mentioned on your new question, why are you using `kafka-bootstrap-servers`? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka

Comment: we have changed configuration in yml file, now we are using spring.kafka.producer.      bootstrap-servers and spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers and in these properties we have set msk's url and communication established properly but in console we are getting localhost:9092 warning ,I have debugged my code twice , we are not using localhost anywhere in project

Comment: 1) Don't use producer/consumer **only** `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`. 2) Make sure the `advertised.listeners` are set correctly and you connect to the proper port in MSK https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/